# Counting total number of matches with grep instead of just how many lines match

Tags: regex, linux, unix, command-line, grep

Does grep offer a way to count the total number of matches it makes?  The -c option only returns the number of lines that matched the regex, but in this case I have multiple matches per line.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -o -E "your expression" file |wc -l
```

well, -E is just an example, it could be -P, -F etc. point is -o

test:

```
kent$  echo "abc xxx yyy"|grep -cP "[a-z]{3}"      
1

kent$  echo "abc xxx yyy"|grep -oP "[a-z]{3}"|wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a -o flag which indicates that only the matched subsection of the line should get printed.

Use that in conjunction with wc -l:

```
grep -o "part of line" | wc -l
```

[man grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) explains it as well.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answers, using just grep:

```
grep -o "seach pattern" somefile.txt | grep -c ""
```

The -o in the first grep outputs each match, and just the match - not the entire line (unless the entire line IS the match, of course).  The -c in the second grep then counts 'em.

It's a few more characters to type (like, 4 or 5), but I find it easier to remember.